# Rotating a PIXI.Graphics element around its center

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have a grid of white squares and trying to apply a mouseover event on each of them which will rotate only the hovered over square a certain degree. I have tried a lot of approaches (setting pivot points, position etc.) but I can't get those little circles to rotate right on their position, they have a messed up rotation center which I just can't seem to fix.

The code is below and the link to the pixi playground is:
https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/2yYbsCe-rMay-VsRBiihC

```
// Define Variables
let width = window.innerWidth;
let height = window.innerHeight;


// Initialise application
let app = new PIXI.Application({ 
    width: width,         // default: 800
    height: height,        // default: 600
    antialias: true,    // default: false
    transparent: false, // default: false
    resolution: 1,       // default: 1
    resizeTo: window
  }
);


document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// Variables
let loader = new PIXI.Loader();
let sprite = new PIXI.Sprite();
let render = app.renderer;
let rWidth = render.width;
let rHeight = render.height;
let stage = app.stage;
let angle = 0.01;


let container = new PIXI.Container();
let count = 10;

let rows = Math.floor(render.height / count);
let cols = Math.floor(render.width / count);

let size = 50;
let margin = 2;

let rects = [];

for (let i = size; i < render.width - size + margin; i += size) {
    
    for (let j = size; j < render.height - size + margin; j += size) {            
        
    
        let rect = new PIXI.Graphics();
        rect.beginFill( 0xffffff )
        .drawRect( i, j, size - margin, size - margin);
        //rect.position.set( render.width/2, render.height/2 );
        rect.pivot.x = size/2;
        rect.pivot.y = size/2;
        rect.interactive = true;
        rect.mouseover = function() {
            rect.rotation += 1;
        }
        rects.push(rect);
        container.addChild(rect);
        
    };

};

stage.addChild(container);

app.ticker.add(function(delta) {
    
  rects.rotation -= delta;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are drawing all rectangles with absolute positioning. In other words, every object is positioned at `(0, 0)` and is rotating around that pivot point.

Setting the pivot to `(size / 2, size / 2)` is not enough, since your rectangles drawn at a greater distance are positioned further than that.

Although you could calculate your pivot point to be placed under the center of the drawn area, you will still have large graphics with a lot of "empty space" rotating around the little square drawn.

Generally speaking, it is a better approach to draw the graphics in the minimal space possible and position them where you need. If you draw your rectangle in the center of your graphics (using negative coordinates), you can leave your pivot point at the origin, see this example:

```js
for (let i = size; i < render.width - size + margin; i += size + margin) {
    for (let j = size; j < render.height - size + margin; j += size + margin) {            
        let rect = new PIXI.Graphics();
        rect.beginFill( 0xffffff ).drawRect(-size / 2, -size / 2, size, size);
        rect.position.set(i, j);
    }
}
```

For example, for a rectangle of size 20, the bounds of the graphics are going to be `(-10, -10)` to `(10, 10)`.

Alternatively you can draw the rectangle from `(0, 0)` to `(size, size)` and set the pivot point manually to the center to force the rectangles rotate around themselves.

```js
rect.beginFill( 0xffffff ).drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
rect.pivot.set(size / 2)
```

Here is the updated playground: https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/2yYbsCe-rMay-VsRBiihC

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. And I will take a detailed look at the mechanism behind it to learn from it.

Comment: so I finally sat and thoroughly read this, and am confused. I mean, how am I placing my rects absolute? and that too at (0,0)? Dont I have the x and y coords of the drawRect method set to the `i` and `j` variables which are distributed throughout the page?

Comment: I found `sprite.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);` to be an easier way than `sprite.pivot.set(size / 2)` to move the rotation point to the middle, but I'm new to Pixi so there may be some important difference that makes `anchor` not appropriate for some cases.